# Removing intermediate table mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, recursion

I have data that is structured as follows:

```
Parent   |    Child
散       |    ⺙
⺙       |    
⺙       |    乂
散       |    38239
38239    |    龷
38239    |    月
```

As you can see, there is sometimes intermediate mapping (i.e., 散 > 38239 > 龷 / 月).

I'm trying to put together a recursive script that will alter the above data to this:

```
Parent   |    Child
散       |    ⺙
⺙       |    
⺙       |    乂
散       |    龷
散       |    月
```

It basically just removes the intermediate mapping. What you can't see here is that sometimes there is **multiple levels of intermediate mapping** (i.e., numbers mapping to other numbers) and we don't know how many levels of mapping there will be, so it needs to be recursive.

My most recent attempt used php loops and mysql queries but it simply takes up too much resources and times out/uses too much memory to be useable.

Is there a pure MySQL solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 2 steps

First set parents and second delete the childs

```
CREATE TABLE `parchild` (
  `parent` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `child` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `parchild` (`parent`, `child`)
VALUES
    ('散', '⺙'),
    ('⺙', ''),
    ('⺙', '乂'),
    ('散', '38239'),
    ('38239', '龷'),
    ('38239', '月');

UPDATE parchild p
LEFT JOIN parchild p1 ON p.parent = p1.child 
SET p.parent = p1.parent
WHERE  CONVERT(p.parent, INTEGER) > 0;

DELETE FROM parchild 
WHERE  CONVERT(child, INTEGER) > 0;
```

Please let me know if it works for you

Comment: Thank you! I will see if this solution works in the morning. But at first glance I wonder if there will be issues with 1. multiple levels of intermediate mapping and 2. if the table was randomly ordered?

Comment: I solved this problem using php and nested loops, thanks for your help!